# When I tap with Detox, the button is not tapped. However it can be tapped if I just click at it

Tags: detox

[image: Tap by Detox, and just clicking at the button]

The problem is when I tap with Detox, the button is not tapped. However it can be tapped if I just click at it.

version of Detox: 16.8.2,
version of React Native: 0.57.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This happened because I used `device.openURL({url: 'https://...' })` previously to open the app from a deep link.

Instead, it worked after opening a new instance of the app with a deep link in argument: `device.launchApp({newInstance: true, url: 'https://...' });`

After this, the interaction can be performed.
It looks like a bug with the method `device.openURL()`